# WYSIHTML5: replace <br /> with <br>

Tags: wysihtml5

I'm using WYSIHTML5 editor. Field value was imported to the database and now I want to display it to user.

Value saved in db:

```
Abstract<br />Introduction<br />Material and methods<br /><br /><br />Material studied<br /><br />Treatment of material<br /><br />
```

Value in editor:

```
Abstract<br>Introduction<br>Material and methods<br><br><br>Material studied<br><br>Treatment of material<br><br>
```

As you can see

```
<br />
```

was replaced by

```
<br>
```

The thing is that we notify user if he changed value of the field and didn't click "save". Since we compare texts, this difference in br tag counts and I want to avoid it.

Is there any way to turn it off in wysihtml5?

Comment: Normalise the HTML on the server and compare the normalised versions instead.

Comment: @Quentin I thought that it's probably some kind of processing in editor I can turned off. But it looks like I will process values on the server side.